# Can we call an external method between before and around advices? (For the same pointcut)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, aop, aspectj

I have a general AOP question, please clarify me on this situation, 
let's assume we have an execution pointcut that catches a method execution :
In our aspect we have a :

```
pointcut pointcut_CatchMethod(Activity activity) :  execution(String methodA(..))
     && target(activity);
```

Here, we have a methodA() in target activity.
and we have 2 advices before and around. Like :

```
    before(Activity activity) : pointcut_CatchMethod(activity){
//Do something...
}

    String around(Activity activity) : pointcut_CatchMethod(activity){
//Do something different.
}
```

So my question is, could we call a method like aMethodIntheAspect() (this method is in the aspect) between these before and around advices. I'm not capable of doing it because I think before and around advices execute in the same time in some manner.

***In Resume, How can I change the value of a global variable in the aspect.? (by aMethodIntheAspect() )***

For detailed code information please refer to this link:
[BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive the broadcasted intent in the right time(Receiver's onReceive is being late to be called)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862310/broadcastreceiver-doesnt-receive-the-broadcasted-intent-in-the-right-time)

Comment: No offense meant, but I read several of your questions and want to suggest you to think more about application and aspect design. Start with the problem in mind and stay focused on finding a proper solution instead of focusing on an assumed technical solution and making it fit your problem. Secondly, please try to explain your intent better, maybe by providing more explicit code examples and fewer unclear explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, It's not possible to make operation like mentioned in the question, So instead of doing this kind of process, I cancel the original call to **methodA()** with around aspect, then calling it manually inside a method inside the Aspect.