# Cancel a method execution with around advice and execute this method manually inside the aspect

Tags: java, android, aop, aspectj

Is it possible to cancel a method's execution with around advice and execute it inside a method in the aspect?

Example :
we have a project that has:

1 -  **An activity** ***SenderActivity.java*** . Inside this activity we have a method **MethodA()** which returns String.

like :

```
public static String MethodA(){
String string = "a string";
return string;
}
```

2 - We catch MethodA() 's execution with a pointcut inside the aspect.aj

like:

```
pointcut pointcut_catchMethodA() : execution(static String MethodA());
```

and the around advice is :

```
String around() : pointcut_catchMethodA(){
//We return null or simply don't call the proceed()
return null;
}
```

So here, everytime MethodA() is tried to be executed, around advice cancels it.

And I'm wondering if after this cancellation, can I do something like :

```
public void MethodToCallMethodAInsideTheAspect(){

SenderActivity.MethodA();

}
```

So by this way, I cancelled the original call to MethodA() and I called it manually inside my aspect.aj. So I want MethodA() to return it's original value. (string = "a String").

Is it possible ? Or if there is a way to implement this, then please don't hesitate your guidance.

Because I tried this kind of implementation and my implementation returned null value when I want to execute SenderActivity.MethodA() manually. I think it returns around advice's value.

Comment: I didn't know aspect programming could work on Android. Any tutorial to start from ?

Comment: I had doubt about it too at first but with a little search I discovered that it's possible also on Android.
Here's a good tutorial to start with:
http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself :

This architecture actually works, it has to be replaced just the pointcut :

from

```
pointcut pointcut_catchMethodA() : execution(static String MethodA());
```

to :

```
pointcut pointcut_catchMethodA() : call(static String MethodA(..)) && !within(Aspect);
```

here, we use within because we don't want our aspect to catch calls that has been made from the aspect i.e.

```
public void MethodToCallMethodAInsideTheAspect(){

SenderActivity.MethodA();

}
```

So this call will not be catched by around advice. So the original call to ***MethodA()*** has been cancelled by around advice and it's called manually by ***MethodToCallMethodAInsideTheAspect()***